# OFDM parameters vs channel parameters

Tags: ofdm

I would like to understand the relation between OFDM parameters and channel parameters. I know the following:

length of cyclic prefix > delay spread

ofdm symbol time > coherence time of the channel

subcarrier spacing >> delay spread of the channel

Is subcarrier spacing also related to coherence bandwidth? One reason is for channel estimation via pilots requires that

subcarrier spacing << coherence bandwidth

Are there any other relationships?

Thanks.